# MediaCodec decoder output is empty

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

My simple app must show a Camera preview, which I created through a SurfaceView, and while frames become available (through 
`onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` 
callback) a secondary thread sub-sample frames and use a MediaCodec encoder instance to encode them in mp4. As soon as encoded frames are available, a second MediaCodec decoder instance decodes them in order to return to raw frames. When I call 
`decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info2, TIMEOUT_USEC)` 
bufferInfo's offset and size are always equal to 0!! How is it possible? I already checked timestamps and they are never duplicated so we have no discarded frames

Comment: Some examples are available on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ . The EncodeDecodeTest's buffer-based tests work with YUV frames.

Comment: OK. Now, I want to render frames onto the screen, but I can't do it. The example renders them onto a hand-made Surface object, which is wrapped into the class OutputSurface. I can easily get a Surface from a SurfaceView but it's not possible to make it the one which is managed by the OutputSurface class

Comment: Back up a step. What are you trying to do? There are various complete examples of camera use in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), such as "show + capture camera" and "continuous capture". Do you really need the `byte[]` from the Camera?

Comment: My app must capture camera preview from a SurfaceView (and until here everything is OK) but just above the first SurfaceView I'd like to have a second SurfaceView where to see in real time the same preview but with a lower resolution. I get lower quality frames by a simple function I wrote to resize YUV frames coming from camera. I need MediaCodec because the decoder API provides built-in funcion (`releaseOutputBuffer(...)`) to render frames onto a Surface. Although I tried to provide such Surface from the second SurfaceView, I see nothing on it

Comment: Are you using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean) for the upper Surface? If you try to put two surfaces in the same position and same Z-ordering, one will lose. Also... are you actually encoding frames as video for the sole purpose of rendering them on a Surface?